# I am getting an issue while generating an particular type of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, self-join

Here we have to take 1st Row's End_Date and add 6 months to it and then compare it with 2nd row's `Start_Date`; if it is before that date then check it's `End_Date` if greater then store `DATEADD(m, 6, b.End_Date)` value into the 4th column `DD_Start_Date` and we have to group it by id.

[image: Required Expected Output]

```
CREATE TABLE Demoo 
(
    id INT,
    Start_Date DATE,
    End_Date DATE
);

INSERT INTO Demoo (Start_Date, End_Date)
VALUES (1, '2010-03-05', '2010-12-13'),
       (1, '2010-12-13', '2011-06-14'),
       (1, '2012-07-06', '2013-03-28');

;WITH a1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id, StartDate ASC) AS Rnm, 
        StartDate, EndDate 
    FROM 
        Demoo 
),
a2 AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.Start_Date, a.End_Date,
        CASE 
           WHEN DATEADD(m, 6, b.End_Date) < a.Start_Date 
              THEN DATEADD(m, 6, b.End_Date) 
           WHEN DATEADD(m, 6, b.End_Date) < a.End_Date 
              THEN DATEADD(m, 6, a.End_Date) 
        END as DD_Start_Date
    FROM
        a1 a 
    INNER JOIN  
        a1 b ON b.id = a.id AND a.End_Date > b.Start_Date
)
SELECT * 
FROM a2
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? SQL Server uses Brackets (`[]`) for delimit identifiers, not backticks (`\` `).

Comment: Please also mention the version of your database.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Right now the logic isn't clear, you didn't show us a current or desire result and also you didn't mention what problem you have.

Comment: @Larnu It's for SQL Server I have edited it. Can you help me with it

Comment: What is your SQL Server Version.